# Real Time CMD Output on Windows Defrag.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, console, cmd

I am trying to capture the output on CMD on REAL TIME. I want to read every line that's being output. The following is my code:

```
private void Defrag2()
    {
        string osDrive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
        Process Psi = new Process();
        System.Text.Encoding SysEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage);
        Psi.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"/c defrag " + osDrive  + " /a /u")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            StandardOutputEncoding = SysEncoding,
            StandardErrorEncoding = SysEncoding

        };
        Psi.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Psi.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutPutDataRecieved);
        Psi.Start();
        Psi.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }

    void OutPutDataRecieved(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DefStat(e.Data);
    }

    private void DefStat(string Line)
    {
        if (Line != null)
        {
            if (Line.Contains("do not need to def"))
            {
                defragstatustb.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => defragstatustb.Text = "You do not need to defrag this computer.")); 
            }
            if (defragRTB.InvokeRequired)
            { defragRTB.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => defragRTB.AppendText(Line + Environment.NewLine))); }
        }
    }
```

That code works well on Capturing CMD output in real time, EXCEPT when I try to run the Windows Defrag in CMD. For example: If I try to enter a command like "Dir", it reads the output in real time, however if I try to run something like "Defrag C: /f /u", it only reads the output ONLY after it completes the operation.

Any idea how to get this working ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multi-threading. Create a new thread and and pass it the Outputstream handler and you are good to go. To test if you need multithreading, put this at the start of the DefWork method:

```
MessageBox.Show(Line);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be already using the Async method and therefore would not need multi-threading ? I am a little confused on what your saying, could you please clarify a little bit more on how to put this in a multi-threading ?